# All text files have disappeared from computer

Tags: windows-10

Recently my laptop stopped working so I sent it in to be repaired. The hard drive had to be replaced which meant I lost all my documents on the device. I restored everything from an online back up and everything worked fine for about a week until today when I noticed all text files have disappeared. This includes word documents, excel files, .py files, .java files, etc. Images and sound files are still there and so are all the folders. Any files that weren't restored properly from the backup are also still visible.

I have tried following [this](https://windowsreport.com/my-files-folders-disappeared-windows-10/) but nothing worked.

What would cause this and is there any way to get my files back without having to do another restore?

Comment: Did you MOVE them from your backup to your new drive. Then the backup is empty (potentially) and then it "backed up" an empty set to your new drive later?  I am not sure I see another reason assuming your new drive is good.

Comment: Are you sure your online backup contains anything else than music/pictures/movies?

Comment: @NatsuKage The back up contains lots of things and I have been able to use the word documents or anything else just fine since until today.

Comment: @John I downloaded the files from a backup so they backup is not empty.

Comment: That is good, so your text files are now there?

Comment: @John No the text files aren't on my computer but they are on the backup

Comment: I suggest you try a Windows 10 Repair Install and then try retrieving the text files again. Use the Microsoft Media Creation Link for this.  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Comment: I don't see a solution without restoring again. Is it possible you never chose to restore those files in the first place? Did you search your drive for those files in case windows updated and left them somewhere?

Comment: Also a Repair Install does keep everything so that is why it is a good starting point for this

Comment: Try : Control Pane > Indexing Options > Advanced > Rebuild.

Answer (score 1):

The very first thing you should do is scan your computer for any potential virus infections or malware.  Some ransomware can remove the file index identifiers in your registry, causing some types of files not to show up, so I would do a search for one or more of the file names without using the file extension in the search.

You could also try a system restore point prior to the visible loss of files.

I personally recall having repaired a ransomware infected PC about 10 years ago that was showing similar symptoms after cleaning the ransomware off.  If I recall correctly, I had to spend about an hour manually repairing registry entries to get all of the missing file types visible again.